# I am trying to do here is I have to run a loop over rows here, in index[7] it should have shown "Sell" but my 2nd if condition is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do here is I have to run a loop over rows and if the condition satisfies it should print according to my command. here, in index[7] it should have shown "Sell" but my 2nd if condition is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
for i in range (n_steps,(len(extended_stock_data_new)-1)):

    if (extended_stock_data_new["Close"][i]<=extended_stock_data_new["Prediction"][i+1]):
        extended_stock_data_new.loc[[i],"Decision"]="Buy"
        if (extended_stock_data_new["Low"][i+1]<extended_stock_data_new["Prediction"][i+1]<=extended_stock_data_new["High"][i+1]):
            extended_stock_data_new.loc[[i+1],"Decision"]="Sell"
else:
    extended_stock_data_new.loc[[i],"Decision"]="--"
    
extended_stock_data_new.head(50) 

output:
0   2020-01-25 08:00:00 3295.26 3298.26 3291.30 3291.75 NaN NaN
1   2020-01-27 10:00:00 3267.88 3269.01 3253.26 3259.76 NaN NaN
2   2020-01-27 11:00:00 3259.51 3269.51 3258.26 3269.51 NaN NaN
3   2020-01-27 12:00:00 3269.76 3269.76 3265.26 3267.26 NaN NaN
4   2020-01-27 13:00:00 3267.13 3267.26 3258.76 3260.26 NaN NaN
5   2020-01-27 14:00:00 3260.51 3266.76 3260.51 3265.26 NaN NaN
6   2020-01-27 15:00:00 3265.38 3266.01 3262.76 3263.01 3264.800049 Buy
7   2020-01-27 16:00:00 3263.26 3264.26 3260.01 3260.26 3263.800049 Buy
8   2020-01-27 17:00:00 3260.51 3263.13 3259.26 3261.51 3260.699951 Buy
9   2020-01-27 18:00:00 3261.26 3264.01 3259.51 3261.76 3261.600098 Buy
10  2020-01-27 19:00:00 3262.26 3267.26 3257.76 3262.76 3262.100098 Buy
11  2020-01-27 20:00:00 3262.51 3263.01 3250.26 3254.01 3263.300049 Buy
12  2020-01-27 21:00:00 3253.76 3253.76 3240.26 3240.26 3254.800049 Buy
```

Comment: Can you tell us which column of numbers in the output has which name? It looks like you might be overwriting yourself by modifying rows 6-7, then modifying rows 7-8, but it's difficult to tell without knowing which numbers are which.

Comment: index, date, open,high,low close

Comment: What about Prediction? I assume it's the last column that's NaN for the first 6 rows?

Comment: no the last column is Decision

Comment: Sorry, second to last column.

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening it that you are overwriting yourself:

when i == 6:

- you assign "Buy" to row i
- you assign "Sell" to row i + 1

when i == 7:

- you assign "Buy" to row i, overwriting your previous answer.

If you don't want to overwrite yourself, you need to add a check to your first condition to see if a "Decision" value already exists.